# Open file with another application

Tags: c++, execute

Hy!

I want to open an .xml file from c++ with a specified application (knowing the path of the file and the path of the application). Same way as you would right-click the file and click "Open with..." and choose the application to start with.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is OS-specific. Which OS?

Comment: @Closer: WTF? This is a valid C++ and OS question

Comment: Sorry I forgot that... I use windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually applications allow command line arguments for file opening. For example, to open a file with notepad you can use command line :

```
notepad.exe a.txt
```

That's why you can use this feature with `CreateProcess` in Windows (which allows specifying arguments) or analogous function in other OS . HTH

Comment: yes, for notepad is working great but the app which I want to start, if I give the path of the file after it, the app opens up and closes immediately

Comment: @Biroka: perhaps the specific application has a specific way of specifying the command line argument

Comment: But if I right-click from explorer and click "open with..." it's working good

Comment: @Biroka: There are 2 ways of specifying the application and command line arguments with CreateProcess. Which are you using? Try the other one :)

Comment: I'm not sure... but I leave it for tomorrow, because now I have to leave. Thanx!

Comment: I don't know why, but the problem comes only when the file I want to open is int the root of my drive (ex: d:\a.xml) if it's in a subfolder (ex d:\folder\a.xml) it works good, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

how about simply:

```
system("application.exe file.xml");
```